# Detect and measure fog outdoors

Tags: sensor, embedded, measurement, detection

Currently working on a project requiring me to detect fog, and measure the amount of fog. It doesn't have to be accurate but it has to give a sense of how foggy it is.

The device (probably Raspberry PI or Arduino) will be placed on street lightning poles. I am currently thinking about using an [Optical Fog Sensor](http://www.opticalsensors.se/ofs.html) as it doesn't require me to have anything on the other side of the sensor with e.g. light scattering techniques.

Is this a good option for my purpose or do you have any other recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Humidity sensor is not good enough?

Comment: @EugeneSh. a RH sensor will probably just saturate at or near 100% for anything from slightly misty to pea soup.

Comment: The professional way is to use a LIDAR.

Comment: Since it is a "get a sense of how foggy it is" that sensor should be enough, to add RH and perhaps temp should increase your ability to sort out false data.

Comment: As Mats said, this appears very similar to how the National Weather Service\NOAA do it in the US: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/asos/pdfs/aum-toc.pdf [page 38]

Comment: @MarkoBuršič A lidar is rather a profiling instrument and one that doesn't perform very well or at all very close to the source.  And unless the OP has a reasonable budget at their disposal I doubt they can afford a lidar anyway, and certainly not at many lightposts!  Some sort of in-situ particle counter may be more realistic, or even image detection.

Comment: Your linked sensor is a 3R classed laser.  Are you allowed to place those on lightposts in public areas?

Comment: Would a reflected IR sensor work?

Comment: Maybe try using a smoke detector. The fog is like smoke is a slurry in the air.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Fog isn't like smoke. Fog is liquid water droplets. Smoke is made of solid particles suspended in air. The linked item doesn't explain the mode of operation of the device so I would think that it is useless for this application.

Comment: Smoke detectors operate on the principle that there is the transmitter and receiver. The LED transmitter normally does not see the receiver. Only the appearance of contamination in the air causes the light to reflect out from the contamination and reach the receiver diode. If it works on the smoke,it can also work with fog. But I'm not entirely sure. It's just theoretical considerations.

Comment: Shine a light into fog and you'll see that the optical method works fine... its a real shame that the answer suggesting this was improperly converted to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Get a humidity sensor, when it reads out 100% RH then you know it's foggy (you don't know what the visibility is however). You can get humidity\pressure\temperature sensors from bosch for cheap (3x3mm or something like that). Like [the BME280](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bme280)

Other than that maybe a photogate like device would be a cheap way to measure fog or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially just use a laser and 2 LDRs? 
Then you could simply measure the intensity of the laser as it is blocked by particles on one LDR and subtract the light level read by the other LRD (Ambient light) to get a good result under a wide range of conditions.

Comment: An LDR is typically a zig-zagged track of about 1 mm width, reacting to the light over an area of perhaps 25 square millimeters. A laser typically has a beam area somewhat less then that. Are you sure that they are a good match to use in a sensor, or are there some essential components missing from that answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, some ideas:

- perhaps a direct humidity/temperature measurement. Im sure with environmental science data you could model, if not actual then probable, fog levels.
- use lasers and measure reflection of light.
- use some sort of range-finding technology - fog will be a function of the distance you can accurately measure... resolution and clarity factors in.
- you could measure the uniformity of ambient light from all directions.  Fog has this magical ability to look the same in all directions, intensity and color.

Answer (score 0):

The official name of such measurement device is called: [Transmissometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmissometer).

I believe this is the standard relevant to the measurement method:
ISO 19289:2015 Air quality -- Meteorology -- Siting classifications for surface observing stations on land.